# Every set that doesn't contain its supremum contains a countably infinite subset.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm self studying linear algebra. I came across this problem, and I don't know how to solve it.

Let S be an ordered set. Let A ⊂ S be a nonempty subset that is bounded above. Suppose
sup A exists and sup A $\notin$ A. Show that A contains a countably infinite subset.

Previously, I had proven that for every nonempty finite set A, sup A exists and is in A. By contrapositive, if sup A exists and is not in A, A is infinite. But I'm not sure if "infinite" <=> "contains a countably infinite subset".

Can I claim that those two statements are equivalent? If not, why not and how do I prove sets with this particular property have countably infinite subsets?

Comment: S is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Any infinite set has a countable subset. Let $\# A = \infty$. Choose $x_1\in A$. Suppose that $x_n$ has been chosen. Pick $x_{n+1} \in A$ with $x_{n+1}\neq x_i,i=1,\dots,n$. This is possible because $\#A = \infty$. Hence $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N} \subset A$ is countable.

Comment: @GlebersonAntunes: no, that is not necessarily true according to this problem set

Comment: Yes, the statement you've already proved is the contrapositive of the statement you're asked to prove.  How you prove that a set that's not finite necessarily contains a countably infinite subset depends on how "finite" and "infinite" are defined.

Comment: "But I'm not sure if "infinite" <=> "contains a countably infinite subset"" That's not a question that can be answered without involving the axiom of choice. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set

Comment: @FZan Andrew Zhang  showed that all infinite sets have countable subsets in an earlier comment. Is his proof wrong? If so,  where? If not, does it rely on AoC? if so where?

Comment: @Tornado547 it relies on AC when you try to formalise "pick $x_{n+1}$". Usually it is formalised as "take a function from finite sequences to $A$ such that it always gives value not from sequence, and then recursively apply it starting with empty sequence". The first part (existence of such function) depends on AC.

Comment: Is $S$ linearly ordered (any two elements are comparable)? If not, then finite subsets of amorphous set (+ something greater than all of them for existence of supremum) ordered by cardinality provide counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

With choice, answer provided in comments by Andrew Zhang. Without choice we can't prove this equivalence.

From [A dedekind finite borel set](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00153-010-0195-6) by Miler, it is consistent with ZF that there exists an infinite Dedekind-finite subset of reals (they actually prove much stronger result, but I don't have a reference for just this at hand). Without going into any details of this construction, we can build counterexample to your statement from any linearly ordered infinite Dedekind-finite set.

Let $S$ be such set, wlog assume $S$ contains supremum (if it doesn't, we can add new element greater than all old). Let $T_x = \{y \in S | y \geq x\}$ and let $Y = \{x \in S | T_x \text{ is finite}\}$.

Note that $f: Y \to \mathbb N$, $f(y) = |T_y|$ if bijection from $Y$ to its image, which is either $\mathbb N$ or its initial segment. $Y$ is subset of Dedekind-finite $S$ and thus Dedekind-finite itself, so it has no bijection to $\mathbb N$ - thus image of $f$ is finite, and so $Y$ is finite.

Now, let $A = S \setminus Y$. It is Dedekind-finite (as subset of Dedekind-finite), but $\sup A$ is the least element in $Y$ and thus not in $A$.